# mac osバージョンが古いと、iosアプリの開発ができない？

Tags: ios, xcode

古いMACを使っています。（high sierra バージョン10.13.6)
APPストアから、XCODEがダウンロードできませんでした。

high sierra バージョン10.13.6では、最新のXCODEが利用できないようですが、
古いmacで開発するといういうのはやはり弊害ありでしょうか？

ご意見お聞かせいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらを使うと＞http://dosdude1.com/mojave/　無理やりできるようなのですが。
どうなのでしょう。

Comment: そちらのパッチは知りませんが、例えばWindows/Linux用のPCにmacOSをインストールできた、なんて記事は時折見かけますが、そのような環境でビルドしたもので提出用のアプリをビルドしたと言う方は見たことがありません。(単に私の探し方が悪いだけかもしれないですが。)自己責任で試してみられることを私が止めることはできませんが、その辺のリスク(規定上はAppleはそう言ったハックを禁止している、よってライセンス停止の処分もあり得る)を犯そうと考えている開発者は少ないように思われます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***古いmacで開発するといういうのはやはり弊害ありでしょうか？***

目的にもよりますが、ありと言えるでしょう。

例えば、最終的に開発したアプリをApp Storeで配布したいと言う場合、Appleは常に最新に近いXcodeでビルドしたアプリしか受け付けないと宣言しています。

> #### [Deadline for App Updates Has Been Extended](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b)
>
> - Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.

上記は *June 30, 2020* を締め切りとする要件の一つですが、今から開発するアプリでApp Storeの審査に通るレベルのものを作ろうと思うと、1ヶ月ちょいでは難しいでしょうから、これが現実的な現在の制限事項になるでしょう。(コロナで(?)延期される前の締め切りはSugiyama Koichiさんの示されたリンク先にあるApril 2020でした。)

iOS 13 SDKと言うのはXcode 11にバンドルされる形でしか配布されておらず、要は

### 今iOSアプリを開発するには、Xcode 11が必要

と言うことになります。

[Xcode wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode)によれば、macOS 10.13.6で動作するXcodeは、10.1が最新と言うことになる(Xcode 10.1のダウンロード自体はできます)ので、それでApp Storeへ提出するアプリの開発はできない、と言えるでしょう。

MacOS 10.14 Mojaveにアップグレードできない古いMacをお使いなのでしたら、そのMacでApp Storeに上げること前提のアプリを開発することは諦めたほうがいいでしょう。

---

学習用にちょっと古いコードが動かせればいい、と言うのであれば、使えないこともないかもしれませんが、その場合でも開発に使用するシミュレーターのランタイムがダウンロード出来なかったり、実機デバッグするためのコード署名が出来なかったりなどの弊害が出る可能性があります。

#### アプリ開発をするには、最新のXcodeを動作させられるMacを用意する必要がある

と思っておいた方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんと全く同じ環境で作業しています。

[Apple Developerのニュース](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09102019a&1568158483)によると、2020年4月以降、新しいアプリとアプリのアップデートはiOS13 SDK、iPhoneXS Max以降の全画面設計をサポートする必要がある、とのことです。

つまり、今後は古いアプリのメンテナンス以外は最新のXcodeでないと開発できないということだと思います。ということは最新のXcodeが動かないHigh Sierraでは開発は難しいということになりますね。

古いアプリのメンテナンスが残っているとはいえ、何かのタイミングで新しい環境に移行しないといけなさそうですね。もともとAppleは高価なハードをOSのアップデートで買い替えさせることに躊躇しない会社だという印象がありますので、今に始まったことではないでしょうが、Macでの開発はWeb関連のもののみ、と割り切って使うなどするしかなさそうです。

Comment: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/